# Finding a formula for a triangle similar to Pascal's.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I need to find a formula expressed in binomial coefficients of the following triangle:

$$D_n^k=\begin{cases}
n \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{ if } n=k \text{ or } k=0 \\
D_{n-1}^k+D_{n-1}^{k-1} \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This triangle is the same as the Pascal's triangle, except for the base value *($n$ instead of $1$)*.

Comment: Here is how the triangle starts (since some people are getting confused):
$\begin{matrix} & & & & 0 \\ & & & 1 & & 1 \\ & & 2 & & 2 & & 2 \\ & 3 & & 4 & & 4 & & 3 \\ 4 & & 7 & & 8 & & 7 & & 4 \end{matrix}$. It appears in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A051601 .

Comment: In the OEIS, Bridget Tenner says $D_n^k = \dbinom{n+2}{k+1} - 2 \dbinom{n}{k}$. This formula, once known, is easily proved by induction on $n$. (Tricky point: It does not remain true if we extend to $k > n$ or $k < 0$ by zeroes.)

Comment: Or, equivalently, $D^k_n=\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [darij grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg) has pointed out, the formula is $$D_n^k=\binom{n+2}{k+1}-2\binom{n}{k}$$ Here is a simple proof that it fits the definition:

$$D_n^n=\binom{n+2}{n+1}-2\binom{n}{n}=n+2-2=n$$

$$D_n^0=\binom{n+2}{1}-2\binom{n}{0}=n+2-2=n$$

$$D_n^k=\binom{n+2}{k+1}-2\binom{n}{k}\stackrel{(*)}{=}\binom{n+1}{k+1}+\binom{n+1}{k}-2(\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1})\\=\binom{n+1}{k+1}-2\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}-2\binom{n-1}{k-1}=D_{n-1}^k+D_{n-1}^{k-1}$$

Answer (score 4):

We derive a formula with the help of generating functions for
\begin{align*}
D_n^k&=D_{n-1}^{k}+D_{n-1}^{k-1}\qquad\ \  n\geq 1,k\geq 1\tag{1}\\
D_0^k&=k\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad k\geq  1\\
D_n^0&=n\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> D(x,y)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^nD_n^kx^ny^k\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  D_n^0x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty D_n^nx^ny^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}D_n^kx^ny^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^ny^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(D_{n-1}^k+D_{n-1}^{k-1}\right)x^ny^k\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{xy}{(1-xy)^2}+x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(D_n^k+D_n^{k-1}\right)x^ny^k\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{xy}{(1-xy)^2}+x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n}D_n^kx^ny^k\\
> &\qquad+xy\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}D_n^kx^ny^k\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{xy}{(1-xy)^2}+x\left(D(x,y)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n\right)\\
> &\qquad+xy\left(D(x,y)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^ny^n\right)\\
> &=\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{xy}{1-xy}+x(1+y)D(x,y)\\
> \color{blue}{D(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-x(1+y)}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{xy}{1-xy}\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> Note the relationship of $D(x,y)$ with a generating function for the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$. We have for $ n,k\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-x(1+y)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1+y)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}}x^ny^k
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we split the sum in order to apply the recurrence relation (1).
- In (3) we apply the recurrence relation (1).
- In (4) we use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n=z\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}=z\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$. We also shift the index $n$ by one.
- In (5) we split the double sum and shift the index $k$ by one at the right-most sum.

We derive a formula for $D_n^k$ from the generating function (6). It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain from (6) for $n\geq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq n$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_n^k}&=[x^ny^k]\frac{1}{1-x(1+y)}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{xy}{1-xy}\right)\\
> &=[x^ny^k]\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j(1+y)^j\sum_{q=1}^\infty x^q\\
> &\qquad+[x^ny^k]\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j(1+y)^j\sum_{q=1}^\infty x^qy^q\tag{7}\\
> &=[y^k]\sum_{j=0}^n[x^{n-j}](1+y)^j\sum_{q=1}^\infty x^q\\
> &\qquad+[y^k]\sum_{j=0}^n[x^{n-j}](1+y)^j\sum_{q=1}^\infty x^qy^q\tag{8}\\
> &=[y^k]\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(1+y)^j+[y^k]\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(1+y)^jy^{n-j}\tag{9}\\
> &=[y^k]\frac{(1+y)^n-1}{(1+y)-1}+[y^k]y^n\frac{\left(\frac{1+y}{y}\right)^n-1}{\left(\frac{1+y}{y}\right)-1}\tag{10}\\
> &=[y^{k+1}]\left((1+y)^n-1\right)+[y^{k-1}]\left((1+y)^n-y^n\right)\tag{11}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n}{k+1}+\binom{n}{k-1}}\tag{12}
> \end{align*}
>
> Note in (12) we use for integers $p,q$, with $p$  non-negative, the convention $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $q<0$ or $p<q$. See for instance formula (5.1) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

*Comment:*

- In (7) we do a *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* multiple times.
- In (8) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$. We also set the upper indices to $n$ since values $j>n$ do not contribute.
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-j}$.
- In (10) we apply the *[finite geometric summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula.
- In (11) we do some simplifications.
- In (12) we select the coefficients accordingly.